# Handlebars: return hash from helper

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

Can i return hash from Handlebars helper? I tried this:

**In my view:**

```
    initialize: ->
      super
      this.hash = {key1: 'test1', key2: 'test2'}
      Handlebars.registerHelper 'show', =>
        return this.hash
```

**In template:**

```
{{show.key1}}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars will see this:

```
{{show.key1}}
```

as an attempt to access the `key1` property of the `show` *variable*, it won't know that `show` in this case is supposed to refer to your `show` *helper*. This is just part of Handlebars syntax and I don't think there's anything you can do about it.

However, you can pass `key1` as an argument to your `show` helper instead. If you define the helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'show', (key, context) =>
    @hash[key]
```

and then use it like this:

```
{{show "key1"}}
```

then you'll get the result you're expecting.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wrykfxyj/

Answer (score 0):

Found another way. Yo can pass context to condition helper like this:

**Helper:**

```
      this.showAttributes = {title: 'title1', author: 'author1'}

      Handlebars.registerHelper 'show', (cond) =>
        return cond.fn(this.showAttributes)
```

**In template:**

```
{{#show}}
    {{title}}
    {{author}}
{{/show}}
```

Works perfectly fine.